# How would you normally implement react paypal with a backend

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

So this is how I've been told to use paypal react integration on my e-commerce site although I'm not sure if it's the best (I'll tell you later why)

```
useEffect(() =>{

    window.paypal.Buttons({

        createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {

            return actions.order.create({
                intent: "CAPTURE",
                purchase_units: [

                    {
                        description: 'book',
                        amount:{
                            currency_code: 'USD',
                            value: 100
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
        },

        onApprove: async (data, action) =>{
            
            completeOrder()

        },

        onError: err => console.log(err.message)

    }).render(buttonsDiv.current)

    // console.log(window.paypal)

}, [])
```

the purpose `completeOrder()` function is to send a request to the backend in order to verify the order before putting a `completed` label in the the order

so the problem I'm having with this is `completeOrder()` runs after the payment was completed and in my experience things like server down or maintenance might occur when the user is paying and that can lead to the user paying for nothing because the order isn't completed

the first solution that I'm looking for is to cancel the payment based on the response from the server. So if the response from the server is an error it will cancel the previous payment. But due to my lack of knowledge is don't see how that's possible

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update:** actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and should not be used in any new integrations

---

The normal solution is to use the official [react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) for the frontend order approval, and the [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK) for order creation and capture via API. Server logic to mark an order as completed should be done in the capture route, before returning the capture result JSON to the front-end approval flow.

For a demo of functions that call a server from approval JS, see [the server demo](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK). You can implement such client-side functions (createOrder and onApprove) from your react code, and have them call the 2 server routes you need to create.